Memory efficient way to convert large raster stack to dataframe and merge with another dataframe
I am trying to convert a large raster stack (4 layers) to a data frame and then combine it with a smaller descriptor data frame in R. I need the 40 rows from the descriptor data frame to be repeated for every grid cell of the raster data frame. Is there a way to do this that is not so memory hungry (it crashes on an HPC running out of memory at 1000GB)?
The reason I am doing this is that I need to feed a dataframe into a model that predicts fire spread (package 'firebehavioR', function rothermel()) and I need the model to run for each treatment combination and each grid cell. As far as I can tell, you have to feed a dataframe into the model (can't be a raster), and you cannot have variables of different lengths [the parameters that provide things plant biomass and moisture content (from my descriptor dataset) cannot be of a shorter length than the parameters that provide things like slope and wind (from the spatial dataset)]
I have been doing this:
# this is the raster stack
rs <- stack('SLOPE_WIND_SM_ras.tif') 
> rs
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 18001, 26061, 469124061, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent     : -97.23903, -89.99986, 43.99986, 49.00014  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
names      : SLOPE_WIND_SM_ras.1, SLOPE_WIND_SM_ras.2, SLOPE_WIND_SM_ras.3, SLOPE_WIND_SM_ras.4 
min values :          56.0000000,          35.0000000,           0.8514639,           0.0000000 
max values :           93.500000,           82.000000,            7.471955,           57.738941 


# this is the descriptor data
# there are 40 treatment combinations
# I need all 40 treatment combos to be repeated for each grid cell of the raster data
data_treatment <- read.csv("data_treat_avg.csv")
head(data_treatment)
# A tibble: 6 × 8
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species              CombinedT LWC_mean H..cm._mean Biomass.g.m2_mean LWC_sd H..cm._sd Biomass.g.m2_sd
  <fct>                <fct>        <dbl>       <dbl>             <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Achillea millefolium Ambient       71.1        12.2              85    NA        NA               NA  
2 Agropyron repens     Ambient       66.0        28.9              10.4   3.97      8.65            19.8
3 Agropyron repens     +N            68.0        25.0              10.3   6.19      5.99            20.1
4 Agropyron repens     +CO2          62.5        28.0              15.5   2.57      4.55            11.3
5 Amorpha canescens    Ambient       56.9        35.0              33.0   4.69      3.03            29.6
6 Amorpha canescens    +N            56.9        27.6              60.7   4.17      6.73            85.4
**your text**

### Converting the raster stack to a dataframe
rs_dat <- rasterToPoints(rs)


### Merging the converted raster with the descriptor dataframe
rep_data_spatial <- as.data.frame(lapply(rep_data, rep, each=nrow(rs_dat)))
final_data <- cbind(rs_dat, rep_data_spatial)


What does range(area(rs[,,1])[ ]) report (this is in km^2) and sum(area(rs[,,1])[ ])? Your stack has almost 2 billion cells given resolution against area; all Minnesota, half WI and slices of ND, SD. Your choices are either aggregate or chunk (subdivide layers) to sizes that can be processed within limited resource (memory). So, break the problem down by fishing for a size that works, taking into account that firebehavioR::rothermel also has its memory overhead. The raster pointer brings the whole raster into memory as it is processed to data.frame and this matters.
